# How to limit the number of concurrent CGI script invocations in Apache 2.2?

Tags: apache-2.2, cgi, bugzilla

How can I limit the number of concurrent CGI invocations in Apache 2.2.x?

More specifically, my problem is this: I have Apache hosting a Bugzilla instance and other stuff on one server. There's very little legitimate concurrent use of Bugzilla. However, it's trivial to mount a Denial of Service attack on the whole server by ignoring robots.txt and simply fetching a lot of bug pages that fork a process and hit a database.

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer greatly depends on your CGI process manager. 
With PHP-FPM via FastCGI, you'd modify pm.max_children. 
With FCGID you'd define either FcgidMaxProcesses and/or FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass. 
With FastCGI you'd most likely tweak maxClassProcesses or maxProcesses.

The documentation for whichever process manager you're using will have the exact syntax on details.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like [mod_cband](http://www.howtoforge.com/mod_cband_apache2_bandwidth_quota_throttling) to perform the throttling at a bandwidth rather than a process level.

Comment: Bandwidth is not the issue. Causing computation in MySQL is the issue.

Comment: mod_cband lets you set a max requests-per-second, which should help.